# How to send Cache-Control: no-cache in HTTP Response header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

Net 4 and C#.

I would need set send to Browser Cache-Control (`Cache-Control: no-cache`) in the HTTP Response header for a Web Form page.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

However, you should know that this header alone won't give you a reliable cross-browser way to prevent caching. See this answer for more accurate solution: [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)

Answer (score 1):

In MVC you can set it in the Controller class, so the View not use cache;

```
public ActionResult User()
{
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dotnet core:

```
Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```